# Как запуститься с другого раздела?

Tags: ubuntu, файловая-система, mate

Очень нужно!
У меня такая проблема. Установил Линукс. На следующий день перестала работать клавиатура и мышь. Сделать ничего не могу. Ещё есть второй раздел с виндой. Сначало тачпадом хотел форматировать раздел с Линукс, думал что наверное тогда будет запуск с виндой, но он не разрешил форматировать свой раздел. Через терминал понятное дело не могу. Экранной клавиатуры нету. Может где то можно запуститься просто так с другого раздела?

Ещё была такая идея чтобы форматировать раздел с Линукс, но он с приложением Диски не разрешает

Comment: Скрин сделанный из `gparted live` в студию.

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в установщик приложений через меню и найди там os-prober. Хотя он должен был установиться и так... но вдруг. Он должен добавить другие разделы в меню загрузки. Перезагрузись. Открой программу Диски - проверь не удалил ли случайно не тот раздел.